# $y(x)=x-\int_0^x xt^2y(t)dt, x>0.$ , $y(\sqrt 2)=?$

Tags: integration, integral-equations, integral-transforms

Given  $$y(x)=x-\int_0^x xt^2y(t)dt, x>0.$$
How to find the value of $y(\sqrt 2)$? Solving using resolvent kernel is lengthy procedure.

Comment: If we assume that $y$ is continuous, then it becomes differentiable. What does FTC give you? Probably some differential equation. Can you solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you write $g(x)=y(x)/x$ you get

$$g(x)=1-\int_0^x t^3g(t)dt \;\;\;\Longrightarrow \;\;\;g'(x)=-x^3g(x)$$

$$ [\ln g(x)]'= {g'(x)\over g(x)}  = -x^3 \;\;\;\Longrightarrow \;\;\; 
\ln g(x) = -{x^4\over 4} + c$$

So $g(x) = A\cdot e^{-x^4\over 4}$ and thus $y(\sqrt{2}) = A\cdot e^{-1}$. Now you have to find this $A=e^c$.

**Edit:**
How to calculate $A$? Bring back to the integral equation $g(x)=  A\cdot e^{-x^4\over 4}$:

$$   A\cdot e^{-x^4\over 4} = 1-  A\int_0^x t^3e^{-t^4\over 4}dt $$
It is easy to calculate this integral and you get $A=1$.

Comment: How can we find c?

Comment: Isn't it t^2 instead of t^3?

Comment: Yeah it is t^3, but how to get the value of c?

Comment: It is g(t) instead of y(t) in the second line

Comment: Thanks.. One more edit it is g of root 2 equals A e power -1

Comment: yes............

Comment: An easier way is to observe from the transformed equation that $g(0)=1$

Comment: Great observation!